# Why does a "/" in commit message break semantic-release?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, commit-message, semantic-release

I noticed that when using semantic-release/commit-analyzer plugin in gitlab ci, if there is a "/" in the commit message this breaks semantic release resulting in the following "error":

```
[7:28:38 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: Update ci_templates/DAST.gitlab-ci.yml
[7:28:38 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The commit should not trigger a release
[7:28:38 AM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analysis of 1 commits complete: no release
[7:28:38 AM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[7:28:38 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/exec"
[7:28:38 AM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/exec"
[7:28:38 AM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  There are no relevant changes, so no new version is released.
```

I wanted to know what is causing that and if/how I can override the configuration to allow for forward slashes in the commit message?

Comment: https://github.com/semantic-release/commit-analyzer/issues/175

Comment: I did come across this issue but its not clear on how I can fix the problem